# Draw overlapped ovals using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to design a shape as similar as the following image:

[image: Overlapped ovals]

Here is my code:

```css
.oval {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 100px / 50px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval">aaa</div>
```

I have problem with the shared part.

Comment: What is the problem in the shared part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a combination of both *pseudo-elements*, `:before` & `:after`, the intended layout can be achieved, as demonstrated in the embedded code snippet below.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
}

.oval:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.oval {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 100px / 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.oval:before,
.oval:after {
  height: 20px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.oval:before {
  content: "C";
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  background: red;
  bottom: 5px;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.oval:after {
  content: "R";
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  background: green;
  top: 5px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

/* Nested anchor tags */

.oval.nested-children:before,
.oval.nested-children:after {
  display: none;
}

br + .oval.nested-children {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.oval a {
  height: 20px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.oval a:first-of-type {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  background: red;
  bottom: 5px;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.oval a:last-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  background: green;
  top: 5px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval">aaa</div>
<div class="oval">aaa</div>
<div class="oval">aaa</div>
<div class="oval">aaa</div>
<div class="oval">aaa</div>
<br><br>
<div class="oval nested-children">aaa<a href="#">C</a><a href="#">R</a></div>
<div class="oval nested-children">aaa<a href="#">C</a><a href="#">R</a></div>
<div class="oval nested-children">aaa<a href="#">C</a><a href="#">R</a></div>
<div class="oval nested-children">aaa<a href="#">C</a><a href="#">R</a></div>
<div class="oval nested-children">aaa<a href="#">C</a><a href="#">R</a></div>
```

**Essential Properties:**

1. `overflow: hidden` declared on containing elements (`.oval`)
2. `position: relative` declared on containing elements (`.oval`)
3. `position: absolute` declared on *pseudo-elements*
4. Applicable `border-radius` properties declared on relevant
   *pseudo-elements*

**Reference:**

1. *[Psuedo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)*:

   > A CSS **pseudo-element** is a keyword added to a selector that lets
   >   you style a specific part of the selected element(s). For example,
   >   `::first-line` can be used to change the font of the first line of a
   >   paragraph.
2. *[::after (:after)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)*:

   > In CSS, **::after** creates a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) that is the last
   >   child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic
   >   `content`<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)</sup> to an element with the content property.
   >   It is inline by default.
3. *[::before (:before)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)*:

   > In CSS, **::before** creates a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) that is the first
   >   child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic
   >   `content`<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)</sup> to an element with the content property.
   >   It is inline by default.

Comment: I assure you I did not see your answer until after I posted mine. Here is an upvote.

Comment: it's rare to see someone well explain his answer and not simply throw code to be fast !, so upvote too ;)

Comment: Is there any way to add link for C, R?

Comment: If you need to link those elements, you'll need to use anchor tags (`a`) instead of *pseudo-classes*.

Comment: I know that but I dont know how to do that in this structure, cause if I do that  overflow not working anymore.

Comment: Technically, you should actually post a new question demonstrating the problem, as the one you describe now it not the same as the one described in the initial problem statement - but, I'll help you out in this regard (take a close look at the updated embedded code snippet and the additional style rules added for nested elements)

Comment: Thank you very much you are awsome

Comment: @user9086883 Don't mention it :) Stay strong, resolute and keep fighting the good fight, 2018 is going to be a good year for you.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.oval {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 100px / 50px;
}

.shared {
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.oval-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval">
  <p class="oval-title">bcr</p>
</div>
<div class="oval shared">
  <p class="oval-title">bod</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! You can use **< >** button in header buttons (in answer or question posts) or using the headers <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false --><!-- language: lang-css --><!-- language: lang-html -->

Answer (score 1):

Well, how much of the image do you want to emulate? How's this for a start?

```css
.oval {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #573;
  border-radius: 100px / 50px;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  font:16px/20px 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
.oval.special {
  background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 30%, rgba(128,128,128,.2));
  color:#573;
}
.oval:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -30px;
}
.oval::before {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  border-radius: 50px 0 / 25px 0;
  top:0; left:70px; width:100px; height:25px;
  background:#573 linear-gradient(to right, #463, #683 30%); color: white;
  font-size:.625em; line-height:31px;
  content:'C';
  text-align:center; text-indent:-70px;
}
.oval::after {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  border-radius: 0 50px / 0 25px;
  bottom:0; left:70px; width:100px; height:25px;
  background:red linear-gradient(to right, #722, #A23 30%); color: white;
  font-size:.625em; line-height:19px;
  content:'R';
  text-align:center; text-indent:-70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval special">BCR</div><div class="oval special">BOD</div><div class="oval special">ASR</div><div class="oval special">EMV</div><div class="oval">STE</div><div class="oval">DVR</div><div class="oval">PVR</div>
```